# firebase analytics not showing logs of custom events from android

Tags: android, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

i am using flutter,android with firebase and i am trying to send a crash on firebase console when a button is pressed using platform channels but somehow my crash aint shwoing on firebase console below given is my code

```
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics;

public class MyActivity extends FlutterActivity {
MethodChannel ft=null;

public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
fa = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
ft=new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL);
}


ft.setMethodCallHandler((call, result){
if(call.method.equals("startlogingfcm"))
  {
   log.d(TAG,"Call received"); //I Am Getting call received in debug logs which shows communication between flutter and native is working perfectally
   FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Throwable("EXCEPTIoN HERE"));

   }
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics expects all Event names in lowercase, with underscores instead of spaces:

i think you are sending invalid event names.

also please check this.
[debugview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview)

Comment: do i need to initialize app using  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); in configureFlutterEbgineFunction ?

Comment: the issue is tried to replace anaylitcs with crashlytics and used

Comment: FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Throwable("EXCEPTIoN HERE"));

Comment: and the app is not crashing with no logs on console

Comment: sorry whats the issue i am not understanding your comments?

Comment: i removed the whole bundle and tried to crash the app using crashlytics

Comment: this is another question just post a question about this problem again with details!

Comment: check Edited Code

Comment: are you running analytics in development mode ?

Comment: try to remove the default filter in firebase crashlytics page